# ICViewPager intercepting touch event from my uislider

Tags: ios, uislider

I've used ICViewPager to act as a scrollview with tabs. When i put a slider in the view, the user has to press the scroll knob for a second before moving it, otherwise the whole page moves with the slider.

I tried:

- setting the slider to exclusiveTouch.
- creating a slider controller and sending the touch event directly to the slider

  ```
  -(CGRect)thumbRect
  {
  CGRect trackRect = [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds];
  CGRect thumbRect = [self thumbRectForBounds:self.bounds
                                    trackRect:trackRect
                                        value:self.value];
  return thumbRect;

  }

  -(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
  CGRect thumbFrame = [self thumbRect];

  // check if the point is within the thumb
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(thumbFrame, point))
  {
      // if so trigger the method of the super class
      NSLog(@"inside thumb");
      return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  }
  else
  {
      // if not just pass the event on to your superview
      NSLog(@"outside thumb");
      return [[self superview] hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I found a workaround by using a custom slider and used the UIGestureRecognizer instead of touchesBegan, touchesEnded functions